# Urinary S/O cat food

Tags: cats, diet, urinary-tract-disease

Is there any difference between urinary S/O wet cat food and urinary S/O dry cat food? My cat had crystals and the vet said to give him the wet food as it was better for him. I was just wondering if that was his personal opinion or if the wet food is indeed better for him than dry food.

Answer (score 6):

Yep it is! Though they both work the same the idea behind wet food is more water intake. For cats we like to see them drink a lot as it makes them pee more frequently instead of holding it in for long periods of time (holding it in gives a chance for stones/crystals to form).